# How to sort an item which is inside an array by query params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning Express.js. I am trying to sort these services by price. All the services are inside an array. Firstly I am filtering the items by their name which is working fine but when I am trying to sort them by their price it isn't working. Here's my code for sorting -

```
const getCategory = async (req, res) => {
  let query;
  const reqQuery = { ...req.query };

  console.log(req.query);
  if (req.query.name) {
    query = Category.find(reqQuery);
  } else {
    query = Category.find();
  }

  if (req.query.sort) {
    const sortByArr = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
    query = query.sort(sortByArr);
  }

  try {
    const categories = await query.populate('services');
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'All Category',
      result: categories,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Here's the screenshot of my query in postman -
[image]
The highest price is **225000**. So the sorting is not working here.

Comment: I can't see what you are passing in req.query but if you want your results to be sorted by a particular field or fields check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are sorted by alphabetical values by default. Use this instead:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a-b);
```